# Convert a list in a pandas df column into a numpy array

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas column with a list of lists.

```
df[0]  
[[[11305.45, 4840.39],  
[11298.25, 4842.75],  
[11292.25, 4846.94],  
[11287.77, 4852.81],  
[11286.58, 4860.15],  
[11305.45, 4840.39]]]
```

I would like to turn the column into an array.

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist()).
```

But I get

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

The desired output is:

```
array([[11305.45, 4840.39],  
  [11298.25, 4842.75],  
  [11292.25, 4846.94],  
  [11287.77, 4852.81],  
  [11286.58, 4860.15],  
  [11305.45, 4840.39]])
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your complete dataframe please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do it directly because `df[0]` is already a list.

```py
np.array(df[0])
```

That is if `0` is a column and not and index of your DataFrame (using numbers for columns can be misleading)